# NodeJS String format like Python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, v8

In python, I can do the following:

```
name = "bob"

print("Hey, %s!" % name)
```

Is there anything similar to that (or Python's `.format()`) in JavaScript/NodeJS?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: You may consider using CoffeeScript it uses whitespace for block delimition like Python and has also list comprehensions. It doesn't provide string formatting but you can interpolate e.g. console.log("Hey, #{name}!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) should do what you are asking for I think.

Comment: But that just prints it, doesn't it? What if I want to do something like `socket.send("NOTICE #channel :My name is %s" %(bot.name));`?

Comment: No? I didn't think so I thought it returned a string

Comment: AFAIK sprintf is not part of node. It used to be a package, deprecated now. Answer by @Alex below should be considered valid.

Comment: The link is broken. This one should work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js

Answer (score 15):

You can use [util.format](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), it's `printf` like function.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

For example:

```
const name = "bob";
console.log(`Hey, ${name}!`);
```