# Python's %s equivalent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently learning NodeJS after working with Python for the last few years.

In Python I was able to save a string inside a JSON with dynamic parameters and set them once the string loaded, for example:

MY JSON:

```
j = {
"dynamicText": "Hello %s, how are you?"
}
```

and then use my string like that:

```
print(j['dynamicText'] % ("Dan"))
```

so Python replaces the `%s` with "`Dan`".

I am looking for the JS equivalent but could not find one. Any ideas?

** Forgot to mention: I want to save the JSON as another config file so literals won't work here

Comment: [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: `s => \`Hello ${s}, how are you?\``

Comment: the only way (that I know) to do that is with a function that takes a parameter and return an object (in this case with the name that you want pass in as an argument)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks, but I want to save this JSON as separated file..

Comment: seems like just syntactic sugar for `j['dynamicText'].replace('s%', 'Dan')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS String format like Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788408/nodejs-string-format-like-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a great npm module that does exactly what I was needed - `string-format`.

[String-Format in NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-format)

Answer (score 4):

Use template literal. This is comparatively new and may not support ancient browsers

```js
var test = "Dan"
var j = {
  "dynamicText": `Hello ${test}, how are you?`
}

console.log(j["dynamicText"])
```

Alternatively you can create a function and inside that function use `string.replace` method to to replace a word with new word

```js
var test = "Dan"
var j = {
  "dynamicText": "Hello %s, how are you?"
}

function replace(toReplaceText, replaceWith) {
  let objText = j["dynamicText"].replace(toReplaceText, replaceWith);
  return objText;
}


console.log(replace('%s', test))
```

Comment: Yeah, but my problem is that I want to save this JSON separated, and without defining the variable first

Answer (score 4):

There is no predefined way in JavaScript, but you could still achieve something like below. Which I have done in my existing Application.

```
function formatString(str, ...params) {
    for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
        str = str.replace(reg, params[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

now `formatString('You have {0} cars and {1} bikes', 'two', 'three')` returns `'You have two cars and three bikes'`

In this way if {0} repeats in String it replaces all.

like `formatString('You have {0} cars, {1} bikes and {0} jeeps', 'two', 'three')` to `"You have two cars, three bikes and two jeeps"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: In Node there is [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), so your answer is quite inaccurate, even though it's correct for in-browser JS.

Comment: Yes agree there is .format in nodeJs but could you let me know why would this is inaccurate for node? you mean this would break in NodeJs?

Comment: My comment was aimed at "There is no predefined way in JavaScript" sentence, as there is a predefined way in Node. Your code would work just the same, but would be kind of reinventing the wheel in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a String.format method, using regex, and the String.replace method:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, p1) => {
        var i = parseInt(p1);
        return typeof args[i] != 'undefined' ? args[i] : match;
    });
}
```

After that, running:

`console.log("{0}{1}".format("John", "Doe"));`

Will output: `John Doe`

Of course, if you don't like editing the prototype of objects you don't own (it is generally good practice), you can just create a function:

```
var format = function(str) {
    var args = arguments;
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, p1) => {
        var i = parseInt(p1);
        return typeof args[i+1] != 'undefined' ? args[i+1] : match;
    });
}
```

Comment: For some reasons I got a "format is not a function" error

Comment: @DanMonero Ok, I forgot that was a custom function I use. Sorry for that, I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

For a few nice alternatives, you may want to take a look at [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

While it's asking for a C-like `printf()` equivalent for JS, the answers would also apply to your question, since Python format strings are inspired by C.